# Why it is impossible to implement ConverterFactory wth typesafe/checked generics?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to [implement `ConverterFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterFactory.html) for all enums. I wrote

```
public class StringToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum<?>> {

    @Override
    public <T extends Enum<?>> @NotNull Converter<String, T> getConverter(@NotNull Class<T> targetType) {
        return new StringToEnumConverter(targetType);
    }

    private static class StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>> implements Converter<String, T> {

        private final Class<T> enumType;

        public StringToEnumConverter(Class<T> enumType) {
            this.enumType = enumType;
        }

        public T convert(String source) {
            return Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, source.trim());
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, checker warns line

```
return new StringToEnumConverter(targetType);
```

with

```
Raw use of parameterized class 'StringToEnumConverter' 
Unchecked assignment: 'StringToEnumConverterFactory.StringToEnumConverter' to 'org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<java.lang.String,T>' 
Unchecked call to 'StringToEnumConverter(Class<T>)' as a member of raw type 'StringToEnumConverterFactory.StringToEnumConverter'
```

Why? Is it possible to satisfy it?

Comment: Generics of the converter are missing: `return new StringToEnumConverter<>(targetType);`

Comment: You have successfully built a `StringToEnumConverter` that you can construct one of for each enum type.  Now, you need to pick an enum type.

Comment: This seems like a lot of effort for something that `Enum.valueOf()` already does.

Comment: @MaxM doesn't work!

Comment: `targetType` is-a `Class<T>`, hence return type will be `StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>>` which is not `StringToEnumConverter<T extends Enum<?>>`, which is required